# Wrapping generated content around selected text from a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to come up with a text editor for a project I am working on and I am stuck when it comes to selecting text from a textarea and then wrapping text around it at a click on a button.

Example:
I would have a button saying `Insert -` once clicked with text selected
`select me` would then become `-select me-`

Here's my current HTML ([jsfiddle mirror](http://jsfiddle.net/bp0cs3ts/)):

```
<div class="container wrapper">
    <form class="create post" method="post" action="action.php?a=createPost">
        <h1>Create a Post</h1>
        <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" maxlength="100" required/>
        <textarea name="introduction" placeholder="Introduction" maxlength="255"></textarea>
        <ul class="options">
            <li><p>Article Edits:</p></li>
            <li>
                <a class="fa fa-italic" trigger="italic">icon-placeholder</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <textarea name="content" placeholder="Article" required="required"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit for Review" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's my current CSS:

```
form.create.post {
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
    form.create.post > h1 {
        font-weight:800;
        font-size:46px;
        letter-spacing:-5px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
    }
    form.create.post > input,
    form.create.post > textarea {
        display:block;
        margin:0 0 5px;
        padding:5px 10px;
        border:solid 1px #CCC;
        border-radius:2px;
    }
    form.create.post > input[name=title] {
        width:50%;
    }
    form.create.post > input[type=submit] {
        width:25%;
        background-image:linear-gradient(#F7F7F7,#E7E7E7);
    }
    form.create.post > textarea {
        width:calc(100% - 22px);
    }
    form.create.post > textarea[name=content] {
        height:300px;
    }
    /*-- text editor --*/
    form.create.post > ul {
        height:auto;
        overflow:auto;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        list-style-type:none;
    }
        form.create.post > ul > li {
            display:inline-block;
        }
        form.create.post > ul > li > p {
            padding:5px;
        }
        form.create.post > ul > li > a {
            display:block;
            padding:5px;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
```

I have no idea where to start with the javascript for this.

Comment: Here is an answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702788/replacing-selected-html-text-in-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702788/replacing-selected-html-text-in-jquery)

Comment: @LShetty, this was written a good while ago, maybe there is a jQuery method? - this also doesn't seem to work with `textrea`

Comment: No, there isn't as jQuery is only a wrapper for JS.

Comment: Isn't simple as: text = char + " " + text + " " + char; ?

Comment: @ManuelBitto i already stated `I have no idea where to start with the javascript for this.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bp0cs3ts/10/

HTML

```
<div class="container wrapper">
    <form class="create post" method="post" action="action.php?a=createPost">
        <h1>Create a Post</h1>
        <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" maxlength="100" required/>
        <textarea name="introduction" placeholder="Introduction" maxlength="255"></textarea>
        <ul class="options">
            <li><p>Article Edits:</p></li>
            <li>
                <a class="fa fa-italic" trigger="italic">icon-placeholder</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
            <input type="button" value="Insert -" onclick="insert('-');" />
        <textarea name="content" id="content" placeholder="Article" required="required"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit for Review" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function insert(val) {
    var editor = document.getElementById("content");
    var editorHTML = editor.value;
    var selectionStart = 0, selectionEnd = 0;
    if (editor.selectionStart) selectionStart = editor.selectionStart;
    if (editor.selectionEnd) selectionEnd = editor.selectionEnd;

    if (selectionStart != selectionEnd) {
        var editorCharArray = editorHTML.split("");
        editorCharArray.splice(selectionEnd, 0, val);
        editorCharArray.splice(selectionStart, 0, val); //must do End first
        editorHTML = editorCharArray.join("");
        editor.value = editorHTML;
    }
}
```